# fetch data from two mysql table for specific user

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT customer_id,created,total_price 
FROM `orders` 
UNION SELECT product_id,quantity 
FROM order_items
```

It is my code to take data from two mysql tables for a specific user.

[image: Photo attached here]

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: Add you code here and then ask your question.

Comment: What do you want your result to look like and what is the relationship between the 2 tables?

Comment: Having looked at the question edits, you are missing the `where` clause that would select the customer_id and whatever else is required to identify the order_items. I suppose an order/invoice number. I have put back the part of your question that was removed.

Answer (score 0):

you must equal number of column when using UNION and in case your quantity is null you can add IFNULL

```
    $query = "SELECT `product_id`, `total_price`, ‌`​‌​created`, IFNULL(`quantity`,0) FROM `order_items`
    LEFT JOIN `orders` ON `order_items`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id`
    WHERE `orders`.`customer_id`={$_SESSION['email']}");
    $order_result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

PS: for accurate reply, please paste the table schema

Comment: Undefined index: quantity

Comment: that means you don't have quantity column in order_items

Comment: or it could have a null value

Comment: Now  I did ....... Thanks Mason.Chase here is my current query = $order_result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT customer_id='".$_SESSION['email']."',product_id,total_price,‌​created,quantity FROM order_items,orders");

Comment: are you sure customer_id is an email address or big integer? you may have to add index to speed it up. please paste your table schema

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `order_id` is a forein key column in `order_items` table, you can use `JOIN` with `COUNT` to get the required value, e.g.:

```
SELECT o.customer_id, o.created, o.total_price, COUNT(oi.id)
FROM orders o LEFT JOIN order_items oi ON o.id = oi.order_id
GROUP BY o.customer_id, o.created, o.total_price;
```

Comment: Yeah... I did    ....... Thanks ALL $order_result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT customer_id='".$_SESSION['email']."',product_id,total_price,created,quantity FROM order_items,orders");